# How to find a transition matrix?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

let $a= \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$

and $b=\{b_1,......,b_4\}$

and $r = \{r_1,...,r_4\}$

Also,

$b_1 = 4a_1$

$b_2 = 8a_1 + 7a_2$

$b_3 = 4a_1 + 4a_2 + 4a_3$

$b_4 = 9a_1 + 5a_2 + 8a_3 + 5a_4$

and

$r_1 = 3b_4$

$r_2= 4b_3 + 6b_4$

$r_3 = 9b_2 + 3b_3 + 9b_4$

$r_4 = 6b_1 + 5b_2 + 3b_3 + 5b_4$

Find transition matrix from basis $a$ to $r$.

-Normally these problems are really easy in class with bases like $\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$

I have no idea how to solve this one.

-thus far I have but r in terms of a:

$r_1 = 27a_1 + 15a_2 + 24a_3 + 15a_4$

$r_2 = 70a_1 + 46a_2 + 64a_3 + 30a_4$

$r_3 = 165a_1 + 120a_2 + 84a_3 + 45a_4$

$r_4 = 121a_1 + 72a_2 + 40a_3 + 25a_4$

What do I do from here? Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

You've done quite a good work there. Let me shed some light on the problem.

You are given three basis, let's call them $A$, $B$ and $R$. You are also given the relation between $A$ and $B$ and between $B$ and $R$:

$$M_{A\to B}=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 8 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 9 & 5 & 8 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$M_{B\to R}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 6 \\ 0 & 9 & 3 & 9 \\ 6 & 5 & 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$

$M_{A\to B}$ and $M_{B\to R}$ are the transition matrices from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $R$ respectively.

Then the transition matrix from $A$ to $R$ is given by:

$$M_{B\to R}\,M_{A\to B}=\begin{pmatrix} 27 & 15 & 24 & 15\\ 70 & 46 & 64 & 30 \\ 165 & 120 & 84 & 45 \\ 121 & 72 & 52 & 25 \end{pmatrix}$$

Which is what you had calculated (we've got the element of the 4th column, 2nd row different, could you check that?).

Now let's think for a moment what this means. If we have a vector $v_A$ expressed in terms of the base $A$, we could know what $v_A$ would look like in $B$ doing $$v_B=M_{A\to B}\, v_A$$
Then, we can also know what $v_B$ would look like in $R$ by
$$v_R=M_{B\to R}\, v_B=M_{B\to R}\,M_{A\to B}\, v_A$$
Hope this clarified your problem.